# Get the width to the left of the table?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I'd like to get the right and left "gutter" widths for a UITableView. Is there some way to access them?

[image: Grouped UITableView]

I'm looking for a programmatic way to do this, especially because it's different on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: It should be 10 pixel from each side. 10+10=20 in total

Comment: Default width is 10 points on each side (so 2x10px on non-retina and 2x20px on Retina displays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a situation when you need to use such a value but if you want to know, you can inspect the frame of `[UITableViewCell contentView]`. The whole cell has width equal to the width of the table, it's the `contentView` that limits the area you can use.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"Cell bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
    NSLog(@"Cell content view frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.contentView.frame));
}
```

Outputs (on a full screen grouped table, iPhone):

> Cell bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 67}}
>   Cell content view frame: {{10, 1}, {300, 65}}

Answer (score 0):

Using grouped table

10 left & 10 right